# Round of double value to 3 decimal places

Tags: c++, rounding

```
double s = 0.320166
```

I want to round off this value to exactly 3 decimal places.
To do this, I am using this code

```
int v = s * 1000;
s = double(v)/1000;
```

When I display `s`, I am getting this result `0.32`.
It is not displaying the 0 at the end. I want to display `0.320` exactly 3 decimal places. I know the result is right, but is there anyway that `0` at the end can also display?

Comment: trailing zeroes are a string formatting issue, NOT a math issue. if you want leading/trailing zero-padding, you have to make that happen via the appropriate string formatting functions.

Comment: `setprecision(3)` will display 3 digits after the decimal.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision

Comment: @Barmar i was thinking the same and yet it still doesn't display it^^

Answer (score 1):

```
char buf[32];
sprintf(buf, "%.3f", s);
```

Comment: This is C code. The question is tagged C++.

Comment: It's perfectly valid C++ code.  It will work in any C++ function.

Comment: Then use the C++ version: `std::sprintf`.

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked perfectly as my requirement

Comment: If my answer worked, please mark it as accepted.  Thanks!

Comment: Or at least up-vote!